# Draw dashed and dotted rectangles on canvas in the same way css border works: draw 4 same edges

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

My use-case is to mimic css border rendering. Is it possible, using the [`CanvasRenderingContext2D::rect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rect) method with [`CanvasRenderingContext2D::setLineDash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setLineDash) to simulate same border drawing as css renderer does, like `border: 5px dashed red`. Consider this example:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 5
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
ctx.lineCap = 'square'
ctx.setLineDash([10, 10]);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(2.5,2.5);
ctx.rect(2.5, 2.5, 195, 65);
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
div {
  border: 5px dashed red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<canvas width=200 height=70></canvas>
```

You may notice the problem is on edges.

[image: Not pretty line joins on edges]

I was trying to modify the gaps and dash sizes, but it seems impossible to get the same behaviour as in the css example: the lines on edges are bigger then the lines on the sides. As a workaround I can imagine to draw every side with a line, but I would like to use the `rect` method to draw in one stroke.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `border-style: dashed` algorithm is not tied by specs, so it will be impossible to render exactly the same in the canvas API.

Then, you've got to know that even CSS renders it line by line: `border` is a shorthand for all the `border-top-XXX`, `border-right-XXX`, `border-bottom-XXX`, `border-left-XXX`.
And that's why it behaves like that : each border has its line-dash set independently of the others.

Anyway, if you want to do it with the canvas API, the easiest solution is to do the same, using four lines, and setting their line-dash separately.

Here is a rough attempt at normalizing the dashes in order to get them always start and end at edges:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineCap = 'square';

// returns a normalized dashArray per segment
// This in no way does the same as any browser's implementation,
// this is just a lazy way to always get dashes start and end at edges
function getLineDash(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var length = Math.hypot((x2 - x1), (y2 - y1));
  var dash_length = length / 8;
  var nb_of_dashes = length / dash_length;
  var dash_gap = (dash_length * 0.66);
  dash_length -= dash_gap * 0.33;
  return [dash_length, dash_gap];
}

function draw() {
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth_.value;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  var points = [
    [x1_.value, y1_.value],
    [x2_.value, y2_.value],
    [x3_.value, y3_.value],
    [x4_.value, y4_.value]
  ];

  points.forEach(function(pt, i) {
    var next = points[(i + 1) % points.length];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(pt[0], pt[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(next[0], next[1]);
    ctx.setLineDash(getLineDash(pt[0], pt[1], next[0], next[1]));
    ctx.stroke();
  });

}

draw();
document.oninput = function(e) {
  if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode === inputs_) {
    draw();
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs_">
  <label>x1<input type="number" id="x1_" value="10"></label>
  <label>y1<input type="number" id="y1_" value="25"></label>
  <label>x2<input type="number" id="x2_" value="350"></label>
  <label>y2<input type="number" id="y2_" value="25"></label>
  <label>x3<input type="number" id="x3_" value="350"></label>
  <label>y3<input type="number" id="y3_" value="225"></label>
  <label>x4<input type="number" id="x4_" value="10"></label>
  <label>y4<input type="number" id="y4_" value="225"></label>
  <label>lineWidth<input type="number" id="lineWidth_" value="3"></label>

</div>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

---

So now, if you only want to use `XXXRect`, you can also create a single huge dash-array containing all of the dashes...

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineCap = 'square';

function getRectDashes(width, height) {
  var w_array = getLineDashes(width, 0, 0, 0);
  var h_array = getLineDashes(0, height, 0, 0);
  dashArray = [].concat.apply([], [w_array, 0, h_array, 0, w_array, 0, h_array]);
  return dashArray;
}
// same as previous snippet except that it does return all the segment's dashes
function getLineDashes(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var length = Math.hypot((x2 - x1), (y2 - y1));
  var dash_length = length / 8;
  var nb_of_dashes = length / dash_length;

  var dash_gap = dash_length * 0.66666;
  dash_length -= dash_gap * 0.3333;

  var total_length = 0;
  var dasharray = [];
  var next;
  while (total_length < length) {
    next = dasharray.length % 2 ? dash_gap : dash_length;
    total_length += next;
    dasharray.push(next);
  }
  return dasharray;
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.lineWidth = lineWidth_.value;
  var w = width_.value,
    h = height_.value;
  ctx.setLineDash(getRectDashes(w, h));
  ctx.strokeRect(20, 20, w, h);
}
draw();
document.oninput = function(e) {
  if (e.target.parentNode.parentNode === inputs_)
    draw();
};
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  max-width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs_">
  <label>width<input type="number" id="width_" value="200"></label>
  <label>height<input type="number" id="height_" value="225"></label>
  <label>lineWidth<input type="number" id="lineWidth_" value="3"></label>
</div>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for the clarification and the demos. I will use lines, as it looks like the most predictable and right way to render dashes, and also dots using 'round'